# How to compare two indicators with their mean value and standard deviation?

Tags: math, compare, mean, standard-deviation, data-processing

I was reading the indicators shown in papers when I found the indicators are compared based on their mean value and standard deviation. + means better, - means worse, and ~ means they are close to each other.
A smaller value is wanted for the indicators mentioned above. As a result, it is clear that if the mean value and the standard deviation are both smaller than others, the value of indicator is better.
However, I wonder that if the mean values of two data are close to each other, but standard deviation differs, how could someone compare which one is better, or these two indicators are close to each other?
For example, 0.0550±0.0024 and 0.0422±0.0010, and the result is ~ according to the paper. Another example is 4.1128±3.4048 and 2.6551±1.1333, the result of comparison is also ~.
However, there's no clue for me to fully understand how to compare these two indicators.

Comment: It would be a question for [Statistics Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (Called "Cross Validated"). I think you'll get more answers over there.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an F-test?